# Select tree with editable options

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-datalist

I'd like to build in HTML a tree of selection options of this type
(Basically I'd like to realize something similar to [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/selectcontent2.shtml) but with one more level and with options which are editable by the users).

FIRST LEVEL
Option 1 (option not editable)
Option 2 (option not editable)
Option 3 (option not editable)

SECOND LEVEL
According to what I chose in level one in a second Select element I'd like to show some specific options (that must be editable by the user so I thought maybe I should use a datalist element)

Like this way
If I select Option 1 in a second list below I'll be displayed with

SubOption 1-1 (editable)
SubOption 1-2 (editable)
SubOption 1-3 (editable)

Then a further level (editable) is included which depends on which SubOption I select.

So if I select SubOption1 I'll have below the following list:

SubSubOption 1-1 (editable)
SubSubOption 1-2 (editable)
SubSubOption 1-3 (editable)

I was thinking about using datalist elements but the issue is that I cannot retrieve which option is selected if I use datalist...meaning I cannot know the number of the option currently selectd in datalist or am I wrong?
Any ideas? Many thanks for your help

Here the code I wrote:

```
<h4>Configure your request</h4><br>
<form id="requestForm" name="requestFormName">
    Select the type of API<br>

    <select id="datalistApiTypes" name="apiTypeSelector" onChange="updateRequests(this.selectedIndex)" style="width: 150px">
            <option  value="0">Select an option</option>
            <option  value="1">Pearson</option>
            <option  value="2">EnglishCo</option>
            <option  value="3">Mobile</option>
            </select>
    <br>
    <br>

    <select id="methodToUse">
              <option value="GET">GET</option>
              <option value="PUT">PUT</option>
              <option value="POST">POST</option>
            </select>
    <br><br> Request URI <br>
    <input id="inputDatalistRequestUri" type="text" list="datalistRequestUri" style="width:600px" onChange="setRequestData(this)" />

    <datalist id="datalistRequestUri">
            </datalist>

    <br><br> Request Data <br>
    <input id="inputDatalistRequestData" class="formField" type="text" list="datalistRequestData"> <br><br>

    <datalist id="datalistRequestData">
            </datalist>

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var apiRequestsList = document.getElementById("datalistRequestUri");
    var apiRequestDataList = document.getElementById("datalistRequestData");

    var requests = new Array();
    requests[0] = "";
    requests[1] = ["Pearson Platform Status Check|https://pearsontest.ispeakuspeak.com/api/v1/ping", "Get Pearson Partners|https://pearsontest.ispeakuspeak.com/api/v1/partners/8d4415ee-1a6d-405a-873a-f36f98b3b9dd"];
    requests[2] = ["Platform Status Check|https://englishcotest.ispeakuspeak.com/api/v1/ping", "", "Get Partners|https://englishcotest.ispeakuspeak.com/api/v1/partners/8d4415ee-1a6d-405a-873a-f36f98b3b9dd,9ac6c60d-8129-40d8-b959-2b43a1d463bd"];
    requests[3] = ["Platform Status Check|https://mobiletest.ispeakuspeak.com/api/v1/ping", "StudentHomepage|https://mobiletest.ispeakuspeak.com/api/v1/student/fd1b215a-2aad-4a30-a944-3abea112f83e/homepage"];

    function updateRequests(selectedApiType) {

        document.getElementById("inputDatalistRequestUri").value = null;
        apiRequestsList.innerHTML = '';

        if (selectedApiType > 0) {

            for (i = 0; i < requests[selectedApiType].length; i++) {

                var optionToAdd = new Option(requests[selectedApiType][i].split("|")[0], requests[selectedApiType][i].split("|")[1]);
                apiRequestsList.appendChild(optionToAdd);

            }

        }

    }

    function setRequestData(selectedRequest) {

        //here I'd like to add a function that does something specific according to the request selected. How can I know which request was selected?

    }
</script>
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Sorry, just added thanks